# refresh contiously in datagridview

Tags: c#

I have written code to show an image in a `DataGridView` winform by the event of `CellFormatting`. It works well but the cell that I have changed to an image refreshes continuously. What should I do?

This is my code in `CellFormatting`:

```
   dgvUnknownPayed.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[colStateImage.Name].Value = Properties.Resources.undo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the cells directly you should modify the datasource.

```
Datagridview1.datasouce = datatable1.defaultview();

foreach (DataRow row in datatable1.Rows)
{
  row.BeginEdit();
  row[2] = ‘Something_Here’;
  row.EndEdit();
}
```

If you want to stop all refresh use this :

`DataGrid.SuspendLayout(); //Stops refreshing`
`DataGrid.ResumeLayout(); //Re-Enable refreshing`

[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a .Net object you use in this case to bind data to your `DataGridView`.

`DataTable datatable1 = new DataTable`  Creates a new instance of `DataTable`.
`Datagridview1.datasouce = datatable1.defaultview();` Binds the datatable1 as a datasource for you grid. This way everytime the table changes, the grid will be updated.

Now to use this table you can proceed this way. (This is just an example)

- You add columns like this `table.Columns.Add("Division", typeof(int));` Where you specify the name of the column and the data type that will be entered in it. Like in SQL Server.
- You add rows like this `table.Rows.Add(Something)` where  something is, in this case, an `Integer`.

It's as simple as this. Change the `Integer` type for anything you want. Don't forget this is just a simple example. Your can add many more columns and rows.

Comment: thanks for your help . but i don't have a cell in my datasource for image and i have it only in my datagridview . please tell me what is datatable in this case ?

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to mark this question as answered with the checkmark under the answer's score if you find the answer you are looking for

Comment: @Mehdi I updated my answer to explain a little about datatables